# VSCode Extension Development Host automatically opens desktop, how to change?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press F5 while developing an extension to launch the Extension Development Host, it automatically opens the desktop directory. I'd like to change this, but I can't find anything relevant in launch.json or settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify: How can I make VSCode open another folder instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling and updating, it just opens the last folder I opened.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a question-answer format - answers should only be used to answer the original question, not to provide updates to your problem. Please edit your original question if you have any further details to add.